# Confusion about output of program

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and I am currently learning loops. In the below program,

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{

    int i;

    for(i=1;i++<=5;printf("%d",i));

}
```

i tried to compile in dev c++ compiler but it is giving error   "[Error] ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: Can you list all the error messages you get, not just that one

Comment: it is showing only one error ,as i have listed out

Comment: `[Error] ld returned 1 exit status` is not the actual error. It is more like a "goodbye" line. Your actual linker errors were reported above that line. Those errors are what you have to quote here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `<stdio.h>` header, and also, main needs a return type (int) and a return value. Changing the program to this will make it compile (at least it did using GCC) and run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int i;

    for(i=1;i++<=5;printf("%d",i));

    return 0;
}
```

The quotes you used in the `“%d”` are illegal too, use normal quotes: `"%d"`.

Apart from that, doing the `printf` inside the loop head might be legal, but it's pretty bad style. Usually in a for-loop you would have have *initialization;condition;increment(or decrement or w/e)* in the head, and do side-effects in the body of the statement.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>  was included

Comment: @PriteshPatel Ok, it wasn't at the time I posted my answer though.

Comment: still question is not solved could u help me in some way

Comment: @PriteshPatel Do you get the same error if you try the compile as it looks in my answer?

Comment: yes ,it is showing same error ,after trying ur code also

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[]) what does this statement mean in ur code

Comment: @PriteshPatel It's a way of writing the `main` function that uses command line arguments, argc is the argument count, and argv is an array of strings that contain the actual arguments. Another legal way to write `main` is `int main(void)` if you don't need/use arguments. For reference see the C99 standard, section 5.1.2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I would try writing the for loop as:

```
for(i=1;i < 6;i++) { printf(“%d”,i); }
```

Comment: u r answer is correct but what if this question was given in exam.not allowed to change statements

Answer (score 0):

1. I have run this program manually on my notebook and i got Output 23456
2. Then i run this on Dev c++ and it is giving the same output 23456 without any error and i have just copied and pasted from ur question dun know why its showing error on ur runtime may be u have not saved it as C file